# how to screwball text view in android

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            android:title="SofAgeTinder"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"

                android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">


            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Item Title"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:maxLines = "10"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_icon64" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="129dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="129dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon64" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml textview15 am printing detail description  but its Overlaping while i tried android:maxLines = "10"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"  but still its overlapping please suggest me where am doing wrong please look my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Always use  `android:layout_below="@+id/item_id"` property in every xml item so that it did not overlap make plus and minus imageview below textView12 so that it did not overlap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            android:title="SofAgeTinder"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"

                android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">


            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Item Title"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:text="New Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:maxLines = "10"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="16dp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_icon64" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="129dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="129dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon64" />

</RelativeLayout>
```